# CodeIgniter - Active Record join

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, join

I got some code in my CodeIgniter model:

```
        $this->db->where('building_active', 1);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('buildings');
        $this->db->join('users_buildings', 'users_buildings.building_id = buildings.building_id');
        $this->db->join('buildings_levels', 'buildings_levels.level_id = users_buildings.level_id');
        $buildings = $this->db->get()->result();
```

What I want to do:

1. I want to select all buildings and join users_buildings if possible. The current problem is, that only the buildings with a corresponding entry in users_buildings get selected.
2. Since there would be no level_id for the second join clause then(if there are no users_buildings available for that building), there would have to be a fallback to change the join clause to buildings_levels.level_id = 0

I hope it's clear what I mean. I don't know if that's even possible.

Comment: `$this->db->get()->result();` or you mean `$this->db->result_array()`?

Comment: Well, there is $this->db->get()->result(); at the end or what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is answered by changing your inner joins into left joins:

```
$this->db->join('users_buildings', 'users_buildings.building_id = buildings.building_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('buildings_levels', 'buildings_levels.level_id = users_buildings.level_id', 'left');
```

That will return `null` for the missing values. I don't quite get if you want that null to be a `0`, `null` or something else.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I decided to delete the second join and solve the problem differently so your answer is all I needed.